# Control over unexported struct fields

Tags: go

So this is my first question in stackoverflow. :)

We have defined a struct in org package like below:

```
type Employee struct {
    FirstName, LastName string
    salary              int
}
```

and then in main.go file, we are initializing the struct like below:

```
func main() {
    ross := Employee {
       FirstName: "Ross",
       LastName:  "Geller",
    }

    fmt.Println(ross)
}
```

The output will be like below:

```
{Ross Geller 0}
```

As salary field is not exported from the Employee struct type, so it's displaying the zero value of int. An end-user will assume that the salary of this employee is 0.

1. So is there any way to control the unexported fields?
2. What is the best approach to deal with such a problem in a real-time scenario?
3. Is this really a problem?

Comment: "As salary field is not exported from the Employee struct type, so it's displaying the zero value of int." No, this explanation is wrong. It prints 0 because salary _is_ zero. Being unexported has no relevance here. If you initialise salary to 12 it would print 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If you want to initialize the field you can always write an exported function or method to do that such as

```
func New(first,last,salary string) Employee{
  //...
}
```

The reason why you can have unexported types is to be able to create something called an opaque type.

You can have methods on your data setters and getters and do complex things without worrying about user braking the internal state of your data.

Imagine you are writing a drawing app and you have a painter Struct which keeps track of cursor and current color and stuff. You really would not want your user to be able to mess with your painter manually. that would break everything.

So the user creates the painter through an initializer and passes it around as a Painter type and using methods  such as `moveTo`,`lineTo` which updates the state internally.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really worried about it, you can override the `.String` of Employee:

https://play.golang.org/p/PncEOGVP2HP

```
func (e Employee) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", struct{
        FirstName string
        LastName string
    }{e.FirstName, e.LastName})
}
```

But in reality, are they going to be seeing the output from the console of your program?  Most likely this is a non-issue.